# django object has no id, or is at least not passing any id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to get my template to pass an object's id to the relevant url, but I'm having no luck. In my template, I'm trying to pass "player.id". The template's name is "show.html" Like this...

```
<tr>  
        
    <td>{{ QB }}  
             
        <a href="{% url 'delete_player' player.id %}">Delete</a>  
    </td> 
        
</tr>
```

The url I'm trying it pass it to is this...

```
path('show/<int:id>',views.show, name="show")
```

The url needs an id but isn't getting one. The problem seems to be coming from the relevant views.py function that I'm trying to link to "delete_player"

```
def delete_player(request, id):
    player = Player.objects.get(id=id)
    player.delete()
    
    return redirect('show')
```

show.html is being rendered by show()

```
def show(request, id): 

    player = Player.objects.all(id=Player.id)

    print(player)
    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated: 

        try:
            QB = Quarterback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            QB = 'empty'

        try:
            RB = Runningback.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            RB = 'empty'

        try:     
            WR = Widereceiver.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            WR = 'empty'

        try:
            TE = Tightend.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            TE = 'empty' 

        try:    
            K = Kicker.objects.values_list('name', flat="True")[0]
        except IndexError:
            K = 'empty' 

        print(player)


        context = {
            'QB': QB[0:],
            'RB': RB[0:],
            'WR': WR[0:],
            'TE': TE[0:],
            'K': K[0:],
            'player': player
        }


        return render(request,"game/show.html", context)
```

when I try to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/show, I keep getting a 404 because there is no id to pass  and subsequently match the path I have in urls.py. I played around a bit earlier today and found "no column "id" exists. I thought django automatically assigns id, but I can't seem to get to it.

For extra reference, here's the object model.

```
class Player(models.Model):

    

    PLAYER_ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Quarterback'),
        (2, 'Runningback'),
        (4, 'Widereceiver'),
        (5, 'Tightend'),
        (6, 'Kicker'),
        
    )
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PLAYER_ROLE_CHOICES)
```

And here's the form that I'm using

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):

    quarterback_name = forms.CharField(label='Quarterback', max_length=100)
    runningback_name = forms.CharField(label='Runningback', max_length=100)
    widereceiver_name = forms.CharField(label='Widereceiver', max_length=100)
    tightend_name = forms.CharField(label='Tightend', max_length=100)
    kicker_name = forms.CharField(label='Kicker', max_length=100)
    

    def save(self):
        quarterback_name = self.cleaned_data.get('quarterback_name')
        Quarterback.objects.create(name=quarterback_name)
        runningback_name = self.cleaned_data.get('runningback_name')
        Runningback.objects.create(name=runningback_name)
        widereceiver_name = self.cleaned_data.get('widereceiver_name')
        Widereceiver.objects.create(name=widereceiver_name)
        tightend_name = self.cleaned_data.get('tightend_name')
        Tightend.objects.create(name=tightend_name)
        kicker_name = self.cleaned_data.get('kicker_name')
        Kicker.objects.create(name=kicker_name)
```

So, yeah, how can I get hold of the id for my objects? I appreciate any attention you might give to this.

Comment: so what you get from `print(player)`

Comment: `player` is not a *single* player, it is a *collection* (`QuerySet`) of `player`s, hence it has indeed no `.id`.

Comment: You delete the player, so what is it expected to show?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I figured as much. I've been trying to add id to the individual objects in the def save(self) function in the form, but haven't been able to make this work. How would I go about assigning an id to the individual objects?

Comment: @Sayse delete_player is supposed to redirect to show.html once you've deleted an object.

Comment: @Alvi15 nothing prints out  while the 404 keeps coming up.

Comment: So why does show need an id? the first line in that is also not a valid query anyway since you're using `all` and then trying to apply a filter within that

Comment: @Sayse I had a feeling show() didn't need an id. I initially thought it did because I am passing "player" in the context. So if not all(), which method would work in this case?

Comment: `all` is probably correct, the `id=player.id` is the incorrect part. `show` doesn't appear to need an id.

Comment: @Sayse Yeah, I've removed that and removed the id from the show url path. As I expected, the error message report is saying "OperationalError: no such column: game_player.id"